# How to find a balance between well structured UX versus visually more appealing UI design?

Tags: usability, usability-testing, user-centered-design

Currently I am having two versions of a Sales Overview page. One (V1) is more structured, researched with some card sorting on users and the other (V2) one is more visually appealing but not that well-structured.

Do you think the best way would be to go online and do a usability test with appropriate questions?

Comment: How exactly is v2 _both_ poorly-structured _and_ visually-appealing? Those two states seem to be at odds.

Comment: with visual treats like data visualisation but occupying space while V1 has a table like view where everything is structured and therefore well overseen/overviewed

Comment: Do you have access to your users? Do you know which they find more useful? Some rhetorical communities love visualizations, some prefer very dense tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say go ahead and test them against each other. That is a form of research too and you might discover insights and pros and cons of both and re iterate on that.

Answer (score 4):

They should not be mutually exclusive. Good design is not subjective and relies on things like appropriate use of colour, white space, typography etc. The more visually appealing an interface is, the more user friendly it should be.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a newbie, but in my short experience i think the best way to avoid subjectiveness is to test. Nothing fancy, 3 users per session and gather real data.
I'm tooking for granted that you're familiarized with usability testing, if you are not just read some Steve Krug books and start to live :)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely perform an A/B test on this. The test may not just show which version is best but will also help you to strike a balance between the two based on user feedback. Merging of the two ideas could work well - all dependent on your customer base of course.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to choose structure between UX vs visually appealing one, but instead, go with one that is both well structured and looks great.

Alternatives:

1. Make a hybrid of the two designs. Interview/test with users to see which one would serve as the best starting point, and then bring elements of the other to that design.
2. Create two different views, if they serve different purposes.

When making design decisions, take into account the types of users you are serving: do they use the product often or rarely? Are they skilled or novice? Do they prefer ease-of-use or power-user features? Are the needs for your users very similar or different?

In any case, now would be a good time to do some tests/interviews with potential users of the page (paper prototyping) and see if they would know how to use the UIs.

Can you share the examples?

Comment: We are still deciding on the last bits ready for the test and then I can share with you.